# Parsing "stop words" using an array list

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I am using a simple code with three for loops to get sentences from Array List, tokenize them, remove stopwords and store the rest in a 2-D array.

SentenceList is the ArrayList.

Stopwords is the array containing the list of stopwords.

The program aims to take each sentence remove the stopwords and save the rest in an array. 
Here's the code:

```
String[][] trim=new String[sentenceList.size()][largest];
    StringTokenizer st1;
    for(int i=0;i<sentenceList.size();i++)
    {
        st1= new StringTokenizer(sentenceList.get(i)," ,(){}[]/.;:'&?!");
        int count=st1.countTokens();
        for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
        {
            String token=st1.nextToken();
            for(int k=0;k<stopwords.length;k++)
            {
            if(token.equals(stopwords[k]))
                continue;
            else
                trim[i][j]=token;
            }                   
        }
     }
    //PRINT CHECK
    for(int i=0;i<sentenceList.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<largest;j++)
        {
            if(trim[i][j]!=null)
            System.out.print(trim[i][j]+" ");
        }
    System.out.println();
```

The confusing element is that the above doesn't work but if I exchange the if and the else part it works and I get only the stopwords.

Comment: Looks like your `trim[i][j]=token;` is in the wrong place.  You want to do that if the token is NONE of the stopwords.  But you're assigning it if there's ANY stopword that doesn't match the token.

Comment: Do you have to use an array for the stop words? A set would be a better idea.

Comment: @DavidWallace: This had been my error. I'll change it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you need...
Problem was that you were adding words inside the 3rd for loop. You should check condition in the 3rd loop, exit to the 2nd loop with break and then process the word (add in this case).

```
String[][] trim=new String[sentenceList.size()][largest];
StringTokenizer st1;
boolean isStop;
for(int i=0;i<sentenceList.size();i++)
{
    st1= new StringTokenizer(sentenceList.get(i)," ,(){}[]/.;:'&?!");
    int count=st1.countTokens();
    for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
    {
        isStop = false;
        String token=st1.nextToken();
        for(int k=0;k<stopwords.length;k++)
        {
            if(token.equals(stopwords[k])) {
                isStop = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isStop)
            continue;
        else {
            trim[i][j]=token;
        }                   
    }
 }
//PRINT CHECK
for(int i=0;i<sentenceList.size();i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<largest;j++)
    {
        if(trim[i][j]!=null)
        System.out.print(trim[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I tried this. Now there's nothing in the trim array.

Comment: Did you debug? Is trim array empty before printing or just print output is empty?
I just tried it and it works for me!

Comment: I spotted the error. I had initiated the boolean to false outside the loop.